# close dropdown menu after click on link and use transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown menu which is almost complete with just 2 bugs/issues that I can't figure out. My nav links to different areas on the home page. So on the home page the user can click a nav link which would instantly take them down to the desired location on the page.

My issue comes as the user clicks on the nav link they are brought to the location but the dropdown menu will not close.

Next to this I also want to animate my menu from top to bottom, so it looks more elegant. I tried lots of things but I can't seem to make it work.. Hopefully you can help me out!

I uploaded this question already this morning but noticed that the great answers that were given to me did not work with the rest of my code. I thus decided to re-upload my question but this time adding my full html/css and js code.

link to my GitHub page: https://kabk.github.io/go-theses-21-sacha-van-alfen/LandingPage.html

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- head section -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rosy Retrospect</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>

<label for="drop" class="toggle">&#x2630;</label>
<label for="drop2" class="toggle2"><img src="images/rose.png"></label>

<!-- &#x2630; -->


<div class="bg-left"></div>
<section class="bg-container">
<div class="bg-left"></div>
</section>

    <div class="page-header">

      <nav>
        <label for="drop2" class="toggle2"><img src="images/rose.png"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop2" />
            <ul class="menu2">
            </ul>
      </nav>


    <nav>
      <label for="drop" class="toggle">&#x2630;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
          <ul class="menu">
              <li>
              <li><a href="#abstract">ABSTRACT</a></li>
              <li><a href="#introduction">INTRODUCTION</a></li>
              <li><a href="#chapterI">I. <br>THE MEANING OF NOSTALGIA IN CULTURAL HISTORY</a></li>
              <li><a href="#chapterII">II. <br>CONTEMPORARY NOSTALGIA</a></li>
              <li><a href="#chapterIII">III. <br>THE TWO FACES OF NOSTALGIA</a></li>
              <li><a href="#conclusion">CONCLUSION</a></li>
              <li><a href="#bibliography">BIBLIOGRAPHY</a></li>
          </ul>
    </nav>


    <a href="LandingPage.html"><div id="title-bar-grey">ROSY RETROSPECT</div></a>
    </div>



      <div class="video-container">
        <video class="animation" playsinline autoplay muted preload loop><source src="images/opener.mp4"/></video>
      </div>


    <div class="flex-container">

      <!-- THESIS -->

      <div class="abstract">
        <a id="abstract" class="subheaders"><h1>ABSTRACT</h1></a>
       
      </div>

      <div class="intermezzo's">
        <a id="intermezzo's" class="subheaders"><h1>INTERMEZZO'S</h1></a>
       
      </div>

      <div class="introduction">
        <a id="introduction" class="chapter-title"><h1>INTRODUCTION</h1></a>
        <br />
        <p>
<br>
<br><br>
<div class="indent">How did nostalgia’s meaning develop from the coined moment of the terminology, and how has this concept been experienced in Europe since the 2000’s (with special focus on the period from 2010-2020) in comparison to the 17th century?</div>
<br>
<p>In order to answer this question, I have divided my thesis into chapters. The <span class="text-shadow underline"><a href="#chapterI">first chapter</a></span> is an introduction to the history of nostalgia. From the 17th century, when nostalgia was seen as a curable disease, to the mid-nineteenth century, when nostalgia became institutionalized in national and provincial museums, historical centres, heritage foundations, and memorials. The past was until that moment no longer unknown or unknowable. The past became “heritage”. Further I will also shine a light on the start of Romanticism and how nostalgia emerged during that time. In the <span class="text-shadow underline"><a href="#chapterII">second chapter</a></span> I will dive more into the technology that once promised to bridge modern displacement and distance and provide a miracle cure for nostalgic soreness. On the contrary, technology became much faster than nostalgic longing. If we claim that progress did not cure nostalgia; did it increase it instead? In the
<span class="text-shadow underline"><a href="#chapterIII">final chapter</a></span> I will look at nostalgia as seen from two different points of view: the positive view on nostalgia; how it directly stimulates creativity. And a more negative view on nostalgia: how it represents a personal insufficiency and an unaffordable luxury as such.
</p>
<br>
<br>
</div>

        <div class="chapterI">
          <a id="chapterI" class="chapter-title"><h1>I.<br>THE MEANING OF NOSTALGIA IN CULTURAL HISTORY</h1></a>
          <br>
          <span>
            <p id="chapterI.I" class="subheaders">I.I THE ACTUAL AND THE IMAGINARY</p>
          </span>
          <br>
        <p>Nostalgia originates from the Greek <i>nostos</i> <span class="basker"><a>(νόστος)</a></span> and <i>algia</i> <span class="basker"><a>(ἄλγος)</a></span>. <i>Nostos</i> means to return home and <i>algia</i> means pain and longing. Almost everyone has experienced nostalgic feelings, though it can be hard to define. One of the difficulties in giving nostalgia a good definition is that the word has changed its meaning throughout history (Salmose, 2012). I will explain more about this <span class="text-shadow underline"><a href="#chapterI.II">later on in this chapter</a></span>. In Boym’s essay, she defined nostalgia as follows: “Longing for a home that no longer exists or has never existed. Nostalgia is a sentiment of loss and displacement, but it is also a romance with one’s own fantasy. The danger of nostalgia is that it tends to confuse the actual home and the imaginary one,” (Boym, 2001, P. XIII). A return home can sometimes turn out as a disappointment. In our head we tend to idealize our past, forgetting about all the negative parts. Even if everything still looks the same, the time is different. This can also be called <i>rosy retrospection</i>, which means remembering the past more positively than it actually was ("Rosy Retrospection", 2020).
       
        <p><br>

        <a href="intermezzo1.html"><div class="intermezzo1"><img src="images/roseblack.png">
        </div></a><br><br><br>

      <span>
        <p id="chapterI.II" class="subheaders">I.II FROM CURABLE DISEASE TO INCURABLE LONGING</p>
      </span>

      <br>
      <div class="images2"><img src="images/Hofer.png">
        <div class="image-footnotes"> Image 1: The original title page to Hofer’s medical dissertation
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
       
<br>
      <br>
<br>
          <div class="images2"><img src="images/Painting.jpg">
        <div class="image-footnotes">Image 2: <i>Evening Landscape with an Aqueduct</i> by Théodore Gericault
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
        <p>
       
        Back then, during the time of romanticism, nostalgia emerged from strong national feelings. Today nostalgia is still used in politics. Tradition is sometimes used an as excuse to approve or to sustain something. As an example, we can look at the <i>Zwarte Pieten</i><sup class="footnote-ref" id="fnref:3"><a rel="footnote" href="#fn:3">3</a></sup> discussion. Every year around November/December it is be brought back up again. Proponents of <i>Zwarte Piet</i> argue that it is a tradition and you can’t take that away from them, as if that legitimizes everything. As Boym would say in a very accurate way: “The mix of nostalgia and politics can be explosive,” (Boym, 2007, P.10). In <span class="text-shadow underline"><a href="#chapterII">the next chapter</a></span> I will focus more on this time period.
        </p>
        <br>
        <div class="images2"><img src="images/Kodak.jpg">
        <div class="image-footnotes">Image 3: Kodak advertisement from 1903
        </div>
        </div>
        <br>
       
        <br><br>
</div>

      <div class="chapterII">
        <a id="chapterII" class="chapter-title"><h1>II.<br>CONTEMPORARY NOSTALGIA</h1></a>
        <br>
        <p> An example of someone who is dealing with restorative nostalgia is earlier mentioned J. Slagboom: he desires to re-construct or relive the ‘rituals of homeland’ in the present. But how does this longing start and what influences it? Like explained in the <span class="text-shadow underline"><a href="#chapterI.II">first chapter</a></span>, nostalgia was defined for the first time to describe the mental symptoms of Swiss soldiers after hearing certain sounds. Still today sound can raise nostalgic feelings, but in the 21st century there are many big nostalgia influencers that were not around in the 17th century. For example, the camera, the internet and many other technical inventions. Technology is also understood to be the driving force of globalization that began in the 18th century and has continued ever since (Shangquan, 2000, P.3). Both improved technology and globalization have had a big influence on how and how much people feel nostalgic.
        </p>
        <br>

        <a href="intermezzo2.html"><div class="intermezzo2"><img src="images/roseblack.png">
        </div></a><br><br><br>

        <span>
          <p id="chapterII.I" class="subheaders">II.I INTENSE INTERCONNECTEDNESS</p>
        </span>
        <br>
      <br>

      <a href="intermezzo3.html"><div class="intermezzo3"><img src="images/roseblack.png">
      </div></a><br><br><br>

      <span>
        <p id="chapterII.II" class="subheaders">II.II HYBRID MEMORY: THE INFLUENCE OF TECHNOLOGY ON THE MIND</p>
      </span>
      <br>
      <p>Like mentioned in <span class="text-shadow underline"><a href="#chapterII">the beginning of this chapter</a></span>, globalisation and improved technology go hand in hand. Technology was once seen as something to bridge modern displacement and distance and provide a miracle cure for nostalgic sadness. On the contrary, technology and nostalgia have become co-dependent. If progress did not cure nostalgia; did it increase it?

          </p>

<br>
</div>
          <div class="chapterIII">
  <a id="chapterIII" class="chapter-title"><h1>III.<br>THE TWO FACES OF NOSTALGIA</h1></a>
  <br>

 

    <a href="intermezzo4.html"><div class="intermezzo4"><img src="images/roseblack.png">
    </div></a><br><br><br>

    <span>
      <p id="chapterIII.I" class="subheaders">III.I VIRTUAL REALITY OF CONSCIOUSNESS</p>
    </span><br>
          

    <br>
        

<a href="intermezzo5.html"><div class="intermezzo5"><img src="images/roseblack.png">
</div></a><br><br><br>

          <span>
            <p id="chapterIII.II" class="subheaders">III.II HISTORY WITHOUT GUILT</p>
          </span>
<br>

          </div>
<br><br>

      <div class="conclusion">
        <a id="conclusion" class="chapter-title"><h1>CONCLUSION</h1></a>
        <br>
      
    </div>
<br><br>

      <div class="bibliography">
        <a id="bibliography" class="chapter-title"><h1>BIBLIOGRAPHY</h1></a><br>
        <div class="image-footnotes">
                  
          <br><br>Tuminas, D. (2019). <i>New exhibition ‘Joint Memory: Photographic Fragments’.</i> Fotodok.org. Retrieved 20 October 2020, from https://www.fotodok.org/en/joint-memory/
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>

        <div class="bottom-panel" id="bottom-panel">
        <div class="popup-wrapper" id="popup-wrapper"></div>

</div>


      <ol>
    <li id="fn:1"><p><i>Simon de Wit</i> was a supermarket chain in the Netherlands from 1951 till 1972, when it became part of another Dutch supermarket chain called <i>Albert Heijn</i>. Both <i>Albert Heijn</i> and <i>Simon de Wit</i> originally come from Zaanstad ("Geschiedenis in detail | Albert Heijn", 2020).</p>

    </li>
    <li id="fn:2"><p>Romanticism is the name of a 19th-century vision of life that is expressed in literature, music and the visual arts ("Romanticism", 2020).</p>

    </li>
    <li id="fn:3"><p>To celebrate the 5th of December, which is the Dutch St. Nicholas holiday, Dutch people gather for parades in which the saint called<i>Sinterklaas</i> arrives in town to hand out candy and gifts. But these parades have taken on an increasingly political tone because of <i>Sinterklaas</i> his traditional <i>blackface</i> sidekick. In Dutch tradition, <i>Sinterklaas</i> has a “helper” named <i>Zwarte Piet</i>, or <i>Black Pete</i>, who appears as a blackface character with large gold earrings and exaggerated big red lips. The number of Dutch people who are protesting the tradition of <i>Sinterklaas</i> his “helper” is growing (Little, 2020).</p>

    </li>

  </ol>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="footnotes.js"></script>
    <script src="navHandler.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}




// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
      &&
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

css:

```
/*
html, body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:100%;
} */
html, body {
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  outline: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* LANDINPAGE */
.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 54vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    position: fixed;
    top: 8px;
    left: 0px;
}
.slider {
    top: 100em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: slider 70s linear infinite;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
@keyframes slider {
    0%   { top:   -150em }
    100% { top: 0em }
}
.slider {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    line-height: 6.5em;
}
.slider p {
  font-family:'OggR';
  font-size: 130px;
  color: rgb(183, 118, 218);
}

.container2 {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 48vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    /* background: radial-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5); */
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 0px;
}
.slider2 {
    top: 10em;
    bottom:-10em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: slider 70s linear infinite;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
.slider2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    line-height: 5em;
}
.slider2 p {
  font-family:'OggR';
  font-size: 100px;
  color: rgb(251, 155, 114);
}

/* TOC */
.toc{
  /* height: 100vh; */
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.toc a{
  font-family:'OggR';
  /* line-height: 10px; */
  font-size:14px;
  color: black;
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

/* TEXT */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'OggI';
  src: url('fonts/Ogg-Italic.otf') format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'OggR';
  src: url('fonts/Ogg-Roman.otf') format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SuisseR';
  src: url('fonts/SuisseWorks-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SuisseI';
  src: url('fonts/SuisseWorks-RegularItalic.otf') format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BaskerR';
  src: url('fonts/BaskervilleMTStd-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
}

p {
  font-family: 'SuisseR';
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    hyphenate-limit-chars: 9 3 3;
}
i{
  line-height: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'OggI';
}
.basker a{
  font-family: serif;
}
.rose img{
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

/* UNDERLINE LINKS */

.text-shadow {
  text-shadow:
    -1.5px -1.5px rgb(233, 233, 233),
    -1.5px 1.5px rgb(233, 233, 233),
    1.5px -1.5px rgb(233, 233, 233),
    1.5px 1.5px rgb(233, 233, 233);
}
.underline a {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'SuisseR';
  color: black;

  background-size: 1px 1em;
  box-shadow:
  inset 0 -0.180em rgb(233, 233, 233),
  inset 0 -0.23em rgb(254, 69, 213);
  display: inline;
}

/* .chapter-title h1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'OggR';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-left: 18px;
} */

.chapter-title h1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'OggR';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  /* height: 100vh;
  top:50vh; */
}

sup {
  font-family: 'OggR', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 11px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.4em;
}
/* .chapter-title{
  height: 100vh;
} */

.subheaders {
  font-family: 'OggR', serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 18px;
}

.image-footnotes {
  font-family: 'SuisseR', serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    hyphenate-limit-chars: 9 3 3;
}

/* INDENT */
.indent {
  font-family: 'OggI';
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    hyphenate-limit-chars: 9 3 3;
}

/* PAGE HEADER*/
.page-header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
.page-middle {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 47.5%;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
.page-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}

/* THESIS */
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 60px;
    /* margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%; */
    padding-top: 20px;
    overflow: scroll;
    z-index: 1;
}

.flex-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.flex-container2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height:100vh;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    padding: 20px;
}


.abstract {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/* IMAGES */
.images {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.images img{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.images2 img{
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
/* TITLE HEADER */
#title-bar {
    font-size: 18px;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: 'OggR';
    color: rgb(147, 37, 207);
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 1vh;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    z-index: 200;
}
#title-bar-grey {
    font-size: 18px;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: 'OggR';
    color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 1vh;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    z-index: 200;
}


.toggle,
[id^="drop"] {
  display: none;
}
nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 400;
  border: solid 0px;
}
nav ul {
  float: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
}
.menu {
  background: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(233, 233, 233, 0.9) 40%,
    rgb(255, 101, 207) 99%
  );
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(233, 233, 233, 0.9) 40%,
    rgb(255, 101, 207) 99%
  );
}
nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  display: left;
}
nav a {
  font-family: "OggR";
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.toggle + a,
.menu {
  display: none;
}
.toggle {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9999999999999999999;
}

/* #drop:checked + .menu {
  display: block;
} */

  .toggle2 img{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 10px;
  }

    [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
        display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateY(0);
    }

  .toggle2,
  [id^=drop2] {
    display: none;
  }

  .menu2{
    background: rgb(255, 101, 207);
    filter: opacity(40%);
    /* filter: blur(50px); */
    /* background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(233, 233, 233,0.9) 40%, rgb(255, 101, 207) 99%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(233, 233, 233,0.9) 40%, rgb(255, 101, 207) 99%); */
  }

    /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
    /* Also hide the  */
    .toggle2 + a,
    .menu2 {
        display: none;
    }

    /* Stylinf the toggle lable */
    .toggle2 {
      position: fixed;
      right: -33px;
        display: block;
        padding:4px 20px;
        color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
        font-size:20px;
        text-decoration:none;
      width: 50px;
      height: 30px;
      z-index: 9999999999999999999;
    }

    /* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */
    [id^=drop2]:checked + ul {
        display: grid;
    }

  /* INTERMEZZO'S */
.intermezzo1 img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  left: 46%;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
.intermezzo2 img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  left: 46%;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
.intermezzo3 img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  left: 46%;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
.intermezzo4 img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  left: 46%;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
.intermezzo5 img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  left: 46%;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }

  /* footnote popup */

  .footnote-ref a{
    color: rgb(254, 69, 213);
  }
  .bottom-panel {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 5;
  }

  .popup-wrapper {
    display: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    /* background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(254, 69, 213) 5%, white 70%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(254, 69, 213) 5%, white 70%); */
    z-index: 5;
  }

  #popup-index {
    padding: 1.25rem 0 0 1.25rem;
    z-index: 5;
  }

  #popup-close {
    padding: 1.25rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
  }

  #popup-content {
    min-width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1.25rem 0 1.25rem 0.9rem;
  }
  ol{
    display: none;
  }

.bg-container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.bg-container-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.bg-middle-top {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 49.5%;
  z-index: 99;
}
.bg-middle-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 49.5%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.bg-left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(233, 233, 233, 0) 70%, rgb(255, 101, 207) 95%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(233, 233, 233, 0) 70%, rgb(255, 101, 207) 95%);
  float: left;
}

.bg-right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 101, 207) 5%, rgba(233, 233, 233, 0) 30%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 101, 207) 5%, rgba(233, 233, 233, 0) 30%);
  float: left;
}
.bg-middle-top {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(233, 233, 233, 0) 85%, rgb(255, 101, 207) 99%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(233, 233, 233, 0) 85%, rgb(255, 101, 207) 99%);
  float: left;
}

.bg-middle-bottom {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 101, 207) 1%, rgba(233, 233, 233, 0) 15%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 101, 207) 1%, rgba(233, 233, 233, 0) 15%);
  float: left;
}


/* //////////////////MOBILE VERSION 800 px////////////////// */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  html, body { overflow-x: hidden }


  .video-container{
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    padding: 0px;
    /* margin-top: 8%; */
  }

  .flex-container{
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 99%;
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
    /* margin-top: 8%; */
  }

  .abstract {
    padding-top: 3px;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    /* text-indent: 13px; */
    padding-left: 13px;
    line-height: 24px;
  }
  .chapter-title h1 {
    padding-left: 13px;
  }
  .subheaders {
    padding-left: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }

  #title-bar > h1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-indent: 0px;
  }

  .image-footnotes {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
  }

  .image-footnotes-italic {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

}


@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {

  html, body { overflow-x: hidden }

  @keyframes slider {
      0%   { top:   -140em }
      100% { top: 0em }
  }
.slider {
    line-height: 5.8em;
}
.slider p {
  font-size: 115px;
}
.slider2 {
    line-height: 4.5em;
}
.slider2 p {
  font-size: 85px;
}
}
```

Comment: Hello. Why are you crossing vanilla javascript and jquery?

Comment: Hi! I have now idea.. I am a beginner making a website like this for the first time

Comment: @sachava do you want something like this: https://stackoverflow-sachava.netlify.app/

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal yes! exactly

Comment: To clarify the reason why this question was closed, it's because it contains ***way*** too much code. You need to create a [MCVE] (emphasis on *minimal* here) that reproduces your problem. If you are still having this problem and need an answer, please use the [edit] link to update your question, following the above-linked guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const toggleBtn = document.getElementById("toggle");
const navMenu = document.getElementById("navMenu");
const links = document.getElementsByClassName("navLink");

let navBarOpen = false;

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (!navBarOpen) {
    navMenu.classList.remove("close");
    navMenu.classList.add("open");

    toggleBtn.classList.remove("close");
    toggleBtn.classList.add("open");

    navBarOpen = true;
  } else if (navBarOpen) {
    navMenu.classList.remove("open");
    navMenu.classList.add("close");

    toggleBtn.classList.remove("open");
    toggleBtn.classList.add("close");

    navBarOpen = false;
  }
});

/* Credit to: Elnatan vazana: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12740967/elnatan-vazana */
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    navMenu.classList.remove("open");
    navMenu.classList.add("close");

    toggleBtn.classList.remove("open");
    toggleBtn.classList.add("close");

    navBarOpen = false;
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition-duration: 0s;
}

nav.close {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

nav.open {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  padding: 30px;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #111111;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#toggle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 20px;
  right: 25px;
  background-color: #212529;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  color: #f8f9fa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#toggle .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#toggle span {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0px;
}

#toggle.open span {
  margin: 0px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

#toggle.open span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#toggle.open span:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}

#toggle.open span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#toggle.close span {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="toggle">
      <div class="icon">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav id="navMenu">
      <ul class="menu" id="menu">
        <li><a class="navLink" href="#abstract">ABSTRACT</a></li>
        <li><a class="navLink" href="#introduction">INTRODUCTION</a></li>
        <li>
          <a class="navLink" href="#chapterI"
            >I. <br />THE MEANING OF NOSTALGIA IN CULTURAL HISTORY</a
          >
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="navLink" href="#chapterII"
            >II. <br />CONTEMPORARY NOSTALGIA</a
          >
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="navLink" href="#chapterIII"
            >III. <br />THE TWO FACES OF NOSTALGIA</a
          >
        </li>
        <li><a class="navLink" href="#conclusion">CONCLUSION</a></li>
        <li><a class="navLink" href="#bibliography">BIBLIOGRAPHY</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

If you do not understand any part of the code then feel free to ask me.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/BaLqbPP

Live Link: https://stackoverflow-sachava.netlify.app/